# Problem with Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have a problem with the following code fragment:

```
<div class= "main2" id ="main">
<fieldset id ='fs3'>
<form action ="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<?php

$query = pg_query($connect, "Select name FROM types") or die("");
$numrows = pg_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0) {

    echo "<br /><legend><center>Some Text:</center></legend><br />";
    echo "<center>Some Text: <select name='querySelect'>";


        while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<option value = ".$r['name'].">".$r['name']."</option>";
                }
    echo "</select>\t";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>";
    echo "<br />"; 
    echo "<br />"; 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

    $querySelect = $_GET['querySelect'];
switch($querySelect)
{
    case 'A':
        $query = pg_query($connect, "Select model FROM urzadzenia WHERE tid=1") or die("");
        break;
    case 'B':
        $query = pg_query($connect, "Select model FROM urzadzenia WHERE tid=2") or die("");
        break;
    case 'C':
        $query = pg_query($connect, "Select model FROM urzadzenia WHERE tid=3") or die("");
        break;
    case 'D':
        $query = pg_query($connect, "Select model FROM urzadzenia WHERE tid=4") or die("Zapytanie nie działa");
        break;
    case 'E':
        $query = pg_query($polacz, "Select model FROM urzadzenia WHERE tid=5") or die("");
        break;  
}
}   
else
    echo "error";

}



echo "</form>";
echo "</fieldset>"
?>
```

After calling this code, shall receive the following error message: "NOTICE: UNDEFINED INDEX: QUERYSELECT"

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending the data as POST, but attempting to fetch it from GET.

```
$querySelect = $_GET['querySelect'];
```

should be

```
$querySelect = $_POST['querySelect'];
```

and better yet,

```
$querySelect = !empty($_POST['querySelect']) ? $_POST['querySelect'] : null;
```

Comment: $querySelect = $_POST['querySelect']; does not work, but your second proposal works great! Thanks.

Comment: Don't use the empty-function. If the argument contains "0" it is considered empty, but you will likely want the "0". You should use isset, like

    `$querySelect = isset($_POST['querySelect']) ? $_POST['querySelect'] : null;`

Answer (score 0):

Replace GET by POST in the following line:

```
$querySelect = $_GET['querySelect'];
```